# Django upload multiple images per post

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I want to let the user upload multiple images per post. Similarly to an e-commerce platform with multiple images per product. But till now the images are not sent to the database.

That's my code so far:

models.py:

```py
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    describtion = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

class ProjectImage(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="products")
```

forms.py:

```py
class ProjectForm(ModelForm):
    image = forms.ImageField(widget=ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple':True}))
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['title', 'describtion']
```

views.py:

```py
def createProject(request):
    form = ProjectForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProjectForm(request.POST)
        images = request.FILES.getlist('image')
        if form.is_valid():
            project = form.save()
            for i in images:
                ProjectImage(project=project, image=i).save()
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'projects/project_form.html', context)
```

project_form.html:

```html
<form class="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
    <div class="form__field">
        <label for="formInput#text">{{field.label}}</label>
        {{field}}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" name="" id="">
</form>
```

settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static'
]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

project urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('projects.urls')),
]
```

app urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.createProject, name="create-project")
]
```

Comment: So, what's the question now? And you should must specify the folder path in `FileField` in which media files are stored, and make configurations in `settings.py` and project's `urls.py`.

Comment: I added the folder-path and my settings.py in my previous post. The problem is that so far the content of the two models is not send to the database

Comment: Yes, it is because you have `image` field in `ProjectImage` model not `Project` model which relate to media folder where files are going to store, and you made ModelForm of `Project` model which has no field image, so they'll not store anywhere, you can make two forms according to your models' relationships. And where is project's  `urls.py` configuration?

Comment: I added the urls.py files. Thanks for your answer. So do I have to make two different ProjectForms in forms.py or should I just use one Model in models.py? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue:

1. You have made `ProjectForm` which relates to `Project` model, but the `image` field is in `ProjectImage` model. So, `image` field is not even passing to the template and you also haven't passed it in `fields=['title','describtion']` in `ProjectFrom`.
2. You haven't made configurations for saving the media files in project's urls.py.

## Solution:

1. You should make two forms in forms.py, first `ProjectForm` which will get the data for `Project` model and second `ProjectImageForm` which will get the list of images, then using `request.FILES.getlist('image')` you can save images which relates to a particular instance one by one in loop as you tried to save.
2. You should make media configurations in project's urls.py

---

---

### Try Below Code:

forms.py

```py
from django import forms
from django.forms import ClearableFileInput
from .models import Project, ProjectImage


class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['title', 'describtion']


class ProjectImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProjectImage
        fields = ['image']
        widgets = {
            'image': ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}),
        }
```

views.py

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from .forms import ProjectImageForm, ProjectForm
from .models import Project, ProjectImage


def createProject(request):
    form = ProjectForm()
    form2 = ProjectImageForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProjectForm(request.POST)
        form2 = ProjectImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        images = request.FILES.getlist('image')
        if form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            describ = form.cleaned_data['describtion']
            print(title, describ)
            project_instance = Project.objects.create(
                title=title, describtion=describ)
            print('-------------------------------------------')
            print(project_instance)
            print('-------------------------------------------')

            for i in images:
                ProjectImage.objects.create(project=project_instance, image=i)
            return redirect('thanks')

    context = {'form': form, 'form2': form2}
    return render(request, 'projects/project_form.html', context)


def thanks(request):
    return HttpResponse('<h1>Form saved.</h1>')
```

project_form.html or template file:

```html
<form class="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.title.label_tag}}
    {{form.title}}
        <br><br>
    {{form.describtion.label_tag}}
    {{form.describtion}}
        <br><br>
    {{form2.image.label_tag}}
    {{form2.image}}
        <br><br>

    <input type="submit" name="" id="">
</form>
```

project's urls.py

```py
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('projects.urls'))
]


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

app's urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('home.urls'))
]
```

Your models.py and settings.py can be remain same, but it's recommended to use
`MEDIA_URL = 'media/'` and `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')`, then you should make nested folders inside it to save images or any files.

> `Note:` You should always return [`HttpResponseRedirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect) after dealing with POST data, the tip is not specific to Django, it's a good practice in general as stated in the [tutorial4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial04/).

> `Note:` Function based views are generally written in `snake_case` not <s>`camelCase`</s>, you may change it to `create_project` from <s>`createProject`</s>.

> `Note:` Add `/` at the end of upload_to as `upload_to='products/'` in FileField in `ProjectImage` model.

Comment: Now, `ClearableFileInput` is not working. It returns an error: `ClearableFileInput doesn't support 'multiple'`

Answer (score 1):

"multiple" is not supported in ClearableFileInput, you can use `allow_multiple_selected` instead. but still only allow upload one item.

This way works for me

forms.py

```
class MultipleFileInput(forms.ClearableFileInput):
    allow_multiple_selected = True


class ProductImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductImage
        fields = ('image',)
        widgets = {
            'image': MultipleFileInput()
       }
```